# Importing a data type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, import, module

I'm trying to import a data type from one file to another.

Here's the module:

```
-- datatype.hs
module DataType (Placeholder) where

data Placeholder a = Foo a | Bar | Baz deriving (Show)
```

Here's the file consuming the module

```
-- execution.hs
import DataType (Placeholder)

main = do
    print Bar
```

When I run `runhaskell execution.hs` I get

```
execution.hs:4:10: Not in scope: data constructor ‘Bar’
```

There may be multiple problems with my code, so what is the best way to structure this so that I'm importing a specific data type from a module and able to view it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to import/export class and constructors:

In your case, `PlaceHolder` is the class, and `Foo` and `Bar` are the constructors.

Therefore, you should write:

```
-- datatype.hs
module DataType (PlaceHolder (Foo, Bar, Baz)) where

-- execution.hs
import DataType (PlaceHolder (Foo, Bar, Baz))
```

Or simpler:

```
-- datatype.hs
module DataType (PlaceHolder (..)) where

-- execution.hs
import DataType (PlaceHolder (..))
```

If you don’t specify what you export:

```
-- datatype.hs
module DataType where
```

Everything will be exported (classes, constructors, functions…).

If you don’t specify what you import

```
-- execution.hs
import DataType
```

everything that `DataType` exports will be available.

It’s generally a good practice to specify imports and exports.